# Laravel 4 infinite slash in url and still works

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-4, laravel-routing

My problem is that these 2 url's behave the same way:

```
example.com/foo
example.com//////foo
```

They both get the requested page "foo" and load in the content from db.
But i don't like this.

So this is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my routes are simple:

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
Route::get('/{slug}', 'PageController@show')->where('slug', '[\-_A-Za-z0-9]+');
```

**Where can i set the second one to a 404?** Is the problem in **.htacces** or in my **routes**?

Comment: Maybe you should show your .htaccess and your routes so people can understand what's wrong in yours. Laravel should raise a NotFoundHttpException in this case.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro done, any ideas now?

Comment: I also am having problems w/ this slash code.

Comment: @swt83 Antonio's rewrite rule did work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a problem in Laravel, but you can redirect to whatever place you like by adding a rule to your .htaccess. Let's say you have a route `/errors/404`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /errors/404 [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT**

Just posted an issue in laravel/framework, to see what the core thinks about this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3608.

Comment: thanks man, i'm not that good with htaccess conditions and rules. It works great, so you made my day, have a beer on me. :P

Comment: Could you please explain me in just a few words how this rewritecondition you wrote works? Tried to find some help on google but there's no clean explanation? Thanks

Comment: Looking at the request url `%{THE_REQUEST}`, it assumes that the domain `^[A-Z]{3,}` has 3 or more characters, so if, after that it finds 2 or more consecutive slashes `\s/{2,}`, it redirects the client to a new route with a code of 301. That being said, `http://domain.com////test` or `http://domain.com/test////slug` will both match.